# Error while testing the handwritten recognition project

Tags: python, opencv, knn

This is the code for testing the handwritten character recognition in OpenCV python using KNN.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import operator
import os


MIN_CONTOUR_AREA = 100

RESIZED_IMAGE_WIDTH = 20
RESIZED_IMAGE_HEIGHT = 30


class ContourWithData():


npaContour = None         
boundingRect = None        
intRectX = 0                
intRectY = 0              
intRectWidth = 0            
intRectHeight = 0        
fltArea = 0.0              

def calculateRectTopLeftPointAndWidthAndHeight(self):               
    [intX, intY, intWidth, intHeight] = self.boundingRect
    self.intRectX = intX
    self.intRectY = intY
    self.intRectWidth = intWidth
    self.intRectHeight = intHeight

def checkIfContourIsValid(self):                            
    if self.fltArea < MIN_CONTOUR_AREA: return False       
    return True


def main():
    allContoursWithData = []   
    validContoursWithData = []             

    try:
       npaClassifications = np.loadtxt("classifications1.txt", np.float32)                  
    except:
       print "error, unable to open classifications.txt, exiting program\n"
       os.system("pause")
       return
    # end try

   try:
     npaFlattenedImages = np.loadtxt("flattened_images1.txt", np.float32)                 
   except:
     print "error, unable to open flattened_images.txt, exiting program\n"
     os.system("pause")
     return
   # end try

   npaClassifications = npaClassifications.reshape((npaClassifications.size, 1))       

   kNearest = cv2.ml.KNearest_create()                   

   kNearest.train(npaFlattenedImages, cv2.ml.ROW_SAMPLE, npaClassifications)

   imgTestingNumbers = cv2.imread("count.png")         

   if imgTestingNumbers is None:                           
    print "error: image not read from file \n\n"        
    os.system("pause")                                  
    return                                             
# end if

   imgGray = cv2.cvtColor(imgTestingNumbers, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)       
   imgBlurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(imgGray, (5,5), 0)                    


   imgThresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(imgBlurred,                           
                                  255,                                  
                                  cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,      
                                  cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV,                
                                  11,                                  
                                  2)                                    

  imgThreshCopy = imgThresh.copy()        

  imgContours, npaContours, npaHierarchy = cv2.findContours(imgThreshCopy,             
                                             cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,         
                                             cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)   

  for npaContour in npaContours:                             
      contourWithData = ContourWithData()                                             
      contourWithData.npaContour = npaContour                                         
      contourWithData.boundingRect =           cv2.boundingRect(contourWithData.npaContour)     
    contourWithData.calculateRectTopLeftPointAndWidthAndHeight()                    
    contourWithData.fltArea = cv2.contourArea(contourWithData.npaContour)           
    allContoursWithData.append(contourWithData)                                     
# end for

for contourWithData in allContoursWithData:                 
    if contourWithData.checkIfContourIsValid():             
        validContoursWithData.append(contourWithData)       
    # end if
# end for

validContoursWithData.sort(key = operator.attrgetter("intRectX"))        

strFinalString = ""         

for contourWithData in validContoursWithData:            

    cv2.rectangle(imgTestingNumbers,                                        
                  (contourWithData.intRectX, contourWithData.intRectY),     
                  (contourWithData.intRectX + contourWithData.intRectWidth, contourWithData.intRectY + contourWithData.intRectHeight),      
                  (0, 255, 0),          
                  2)                       

    imgROI = imgThresh[contourWithData.intRectY : contourWithData.intRectY + contourWithData.intRectHeight,     
                       contourWithData.intRectX : contourWithData.intRectX + contourWithData.intRectWidth]

    imgROIResized = cv2.resize(imgROI, (RESIZED_IMAGE_WIDTH, RESIZED_IMAGE_HEIGHT))             

    npaROIResized = imgROIResized.reshape((1, RESIZED_IMAGE_WIDTH * RESIZED_IMAGE_HEIGHT))      

    npaROIResized = np.float32(npaROIResized)       

    retval, npaResults, neigh_resp, dists = kNearest.findNearest(npaROIResized, k = 1)     

    strCurrentChar = str(chr(int(npaResults[0][0])))                                             

    strFinalString = strFinalString + strCurrentChar            
# end for

print "\n" + strFinalString + "\n"                  

cv2.imshow("imgTestingNumbers", imgTestingNumbers)      
cv2.waitKey(0)                                          

cv2.destroyAllWindows()             

return


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
# end if
```

And, I'm getting the following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

File "C:\Users\malmad\Desktop\cip\Testing1.py", line 141, in 
    main()
  File "C:\Users\malmad\Desktop\cip\Testing1.py", line 60, in main
    kNearest.train(npaFlattenedImages, cv2.ml.ROW_SAMPLE, npaClassifications)
error: C:\builds\master_PackSlaveAddon-win32-vc12-static\opencv\modules\ml\src\data.cpp:290: error: (-215) (layout == ROW_SAMPLE && responses.rows == nsamples) || (layout == COL_SAMPLE && responses.cols == nsamples) in function cv::ml::TrainDataImpl::setData

How should i proceed? Sorry for the bad indentation!! I'm new to stack overflow